# TcpClient vs WebClient with CCProxy

Tags: c#, proxy, tcpclient

I have This code :

```
        using (TcpClient tc = new TcpClient())
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            //string Data = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:123"));
            //tc.Connect("bot.whatismyipaddress.com", 80);
            //tc.Connect("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx", 3128); external proxy works
            try
            {
                //tc.Connect("192.168.1.2", 808); internal proxy doesn't work
                using (NetworkStream ns = tc.GetStream())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns))
                        {
                            sw.Write(@"GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: bot.whatismyipaddress.com
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36 OPR/28.0.1750.40
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

");
                            sw.Flush();
                            string Res = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            richTextBox1.Text = Res;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Which working great with any external proxy URL, but I want to try the authentication part so I used CCProxy then I realized that the code doesn't work with local CCProxy (although the WebClient works well) , the TcpClient respond is totally empty.

I don't know how it can work externally and doesn't internally !
[edit]
Is there a way to test the authentication other than ccproxy?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What sort of proxy is "CCProxy" exactly? An HTTP proxy? To support HTTP proxies you need to craft special HTTP requests and send them to the proxy, and your code isn't doing that. WebClient and such can take care of that automatically. Why not just use those?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen : I already know how to work with WebClient but I want to learn how to deal with TcpClient and Yes it's HTTP proxy which listening on port 808.
But it did work with the external proxy so well !!

Comment: Give me another way to test the authentication .. the proxy code works good with external proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Here is the answer

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytes;
        using (TcpClient tc = new TcpClient("192.168.1.2", 808))
        {                
            button1.Enabled = false;                
            NetworkStream stream = tc.GetStream();

            // Establish Tcp tunnel
            byte[] tunnelRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("CONNECT {0}:80  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n", "bot.whatismyipaddress.com"));
            stream.Write(tunnelRequest, 0, tunnelRequest.Length);
            stream.Flush();

            // Read response to CONNECT request
            bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            richTextBox1.Text  = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
            // Establish Get
            tunnelRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(@"GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: bot.whatismyipaddress.com
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36 OPR/28.0.1750.40
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

"));
            stream.Write(tunnelRequest, 0, tunnelRequest.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            richTextBox1.Text += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
            button1.Enabled = true;
```

I have to 'CONNECT' the proxy first to open connection through it then I send the 'GET' as usual.
and to implement the user and pass (Basic authorization)

```
string Data = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:123"));
byte[] tunnelRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("CONNECT {0}:80  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\nProxy-Authorization: Basic {1}\r\n\r\n", "bot.whatismyipaddress.com", Data));
```